# Keyboard and shortcut keys not working in Android Studio in Windows

Tags: android-studio

I am new to Android Studio. I recently installed Android Studio 4.0. The keyboard is not working in the Editor. The text cursor just blinks but does not respond to the keyboard. It works when I press 's' but again the same problem arises when I select any text in the editor. Also, any of the shortcut keys except Ctrl + Z does not work. Please Help me out with this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Don't spam with irrelevant tags

Answer (score 0):

If set-up everything good, then close all project and open again your Android Studio....